# Using an Enum in C#

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, enums

How would I create a C# Enum to store data that needs to be in the format below?

Say I have a small list of items and I want to store them in an Enum.
I have only seen examples like below:

```
enum myThing : int {
    None = 0,
    Read = 1,
    Write = 2,
    Modify = 4,
    Delete = 8
    Create = 16,
    All = Read | Write | Modify | Delete | Create
}
```

**What I need to store is something like:**

- Item_Name (string)
- Item_Is_Multi_coloured (boolean)
- Item_Is_Expensive (boolean)

How would I declare an enum that will store the above three attributes of an item?

Comment: That's called a class, e.g.: `class Item{ string ItemName{get;set;} bool IsMultiColoured{get;set;} bool IsExpensive{get;set;} }`

Comment: So you're talking about each enum corresponding to 3 pieces of data?

Comment: Why do you think enum should be here? As far as I can see, you can have an enum for Item_Is_Multi_coloured x Item_Is_Expensive, like { NONE = 0, ITEM_IS_EXPENSIVE = 1, ITEM_IS_MULTICOLORED = 2, ALL = ITEM_IS_EXPENSIVE | ITEM_IS_MULTICOLORED }. And wrap it into a class with also a ITEM_NAME in it.

Comment: @j.i.h. Yes................................................                                                          .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't store String within enums, you should declare a class:

```
  // The simplest MyItem version
  public class MyItem {
    public String Name {get; set}
    public Boolean Is_Multi_coloured {get; set}
    public Boolean Is_Expensive {get; set}
  }
```

The only options you can cram into enum are item_Is_Multi_coloured and item_Is_Expensive:

```
  [Flags()]
  public enum MyItemKind {
    None = 0,
    Is_Multi_coloured = 1,
    Is_Expensive = 2 
  }
```

And so the modified class MyItem will be

```
  // MyItem with enum (the simplest version)
  public class MyItem {
    public String Name {get; set}
    public MyItemKind Kind {get; set}
  }
```

Comment: Ahh, 10secs faster :)

Comment: +1 for the proposal of a simple class! -1 for the proposal of the MyItemKind enum, though - multi-coloured, expensive items just disappeared...

Comment: @Tom Tom: Sorry, -1 will be deserved if there's no [Flags] attribute, but since MyItemKind declared with [FlagsAttribute] you can set MyItemKind.Is_Multi_coloured | MyItemKind.Is_Expensive for expensive multi-colored items.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: Thanks for calling me out - not seen this before! +1 after all. :)

Answer (score 1):

C# unlike Java can have enum inherited only from numeric types (char, byte, long, int). If you want something more complex, I suggest using one "heavy" class and one enum like this:

```
public enum MyThingSimple : int {
  Enum1 = 0,
  Enum2 = 1
}

public sealed class MyThingComplex {
  public string Name { get; private set; }
  public bool IsMultiColoured { get; private set; }
  public bool IsExpensive { get; set; }
  public MyThingSimple Value { get; private set; }

  public static readonly MyThingComplex Enum1 = new MyThingComplex {
    IsExpensive = false,
    IsMultiColoured = true,
    Value = MyThingSimple.Enum1,
    Name = "Enum1"
  };
  public static readonly MyThingComplex Enum2 = new MyThingComplex {
    IsExpensive = false,
    IsMultiColoured = true,
    Value = MyThingSimple.Enum2,
    Name = "Enum2"
  };
  private static readonly Dictionary<MyThingSimple, MyThingComplex> m_Mapping = 
    new Dictionary<MyThingSimple,MyThingComplex> {
      { MyThingSimple.Enum1, Enum1 },
      { MyThingSimple.Enum2, Enum2 }
  };

  public static MyThingComplex FromSimple(MyThingSimple simpleThing) {
    return m_Mapping[simpleThing];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Enums only allow for one type, have you tried using a Struct? (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ah19swz4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can create enum of boolean properties as below

```
enum myThing : int {
item_Is_Multi_coloured= 0,
item_Is_Not_Multi_coloured= 1,
item_Is_Expensive = 2,
item_Is_Not_Expensive = 4,

}
```

but you cannot create enum on name property

so it looks like you want a class from your item object

if that is the case then you can do like this

```
class Item
{ 
string ItemName{get;set;}
bool IsMultiColoured{get;set;}
bool IsExpensive{get;set;} 
}
```

**Note: class author is Tim Schmelter**

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just using a class and another static container class with properties that return your defined class objects, eg.

```
class Item
{
    readonly bool IsMulticolored;
    readonly bool IsExpensive;
    readonly string Name;

    Item(string Name, bool IsMulticolored, bool IsExpensive)
    {
        me.Name = Name;
        me.IsMulticolored = IsMulticolored;
        me.IsExpensive = IsExpensive;
    }
}

static class Items
{
    const _itemA = new Item("thing", true, true);

    static Item ItemA
    {
        get{ return _itemA; }
    }
}
```

Then you get the stability of `enum`s, and you can refer to them in a natural way, e.g. `Items.ItemA.Name`